# Understanding jQuery AJAX events - success and ajaxSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

Need some help understanding the difference between the `success` and `ajaxSuccess` events documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).

`success` is a local event, while `ajaxSuccess` is a global event. I understand the difference between a local and global variable, but am having some trouble understanding the concept of event scope.

What are some sample scenarios where one would be preferred over the other?

Comment: `ajaxSuccess` will be raised for *every* ajax request sent. `success` applies to a single request.

Comment: OK, so something like show/hide of a loading or failed request dialog would be a good candidate for the global events?

Comment: It's best used where you need the same code to be run for selected events of a lot of AJAX requests. For example, set a global error handler which displays a modal message to the user whenever a request fails.

Comment: candidate tasks for global events are those tasks you need to repeat to every success or error event (e.g hide an ajax loader running into the UI)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use global events as such:

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function(){
//do my global thing here
});
```

as the global event will fire for every ajax call success, not just the one.

but the

```
success: function(){/* do local here */});
```

ONLY fires within the local ajax call function as a private object of that.

Note the

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(){ });
```

might be what you are after as it fires on the complete - with or without an error.

EDIT: Special note of the local `success:` in ajaxSetup global: (this is NOT recommended and you should use the `$.ajaxSuccess`)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success: function() {
       // local within the ajaxSetup
    }
});
```

Now, why would we use one over the other?  Perhaps you need special filtering of the object returned:

```
$(selector1).ajax({
    success: function(data){
        processMySelector1JSON(data);
    }
});
$(selectorOther).ajax({
    success: function(data){
        processMySelectorOtherJSON(data);
    }
});
$.ajaxSuccess(function(){
  $('#message').text('Ajax Done!').fadeIn(function(){$(this).fadeOut();});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`success: function()` is better since this event is only called if the request was successful. It checks errors from the server and, errors with the data makes it the better one.